# Send keys using directinput in Java?

Tags: java, sendkeys, sikuli, directinput

I'm trying to send a few simple keys to a DirectX 11 game after a certain picture is shown on screen.

Problem is the proper keys isn't being sent through the robot class, VK_UP simply isn't being sent.

My thought was to send through directinput instead and just hope it works, but I don't know how to do this in Java?

Re-write in C# isn't an option since I'm using sikuli for Java for image recognition.

Comment: Have you tried http://www.hardcode.de/jxinput/? It seems it implement Microsoft DirectInput

Comment: From what I've understood JXInput is only for implementing support for gaming devices in your Java application? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try https://github.com/umer0586/winKeyboard

```
Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
keyboard.winKeyPress(ScanCode.DIK_UP);
//Thread.sleep(1000);
keyboard.winKeyRelease(ScanCode.DIK_UP);
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of key combination are you looking for? 
Here is a link about keys in Sikuli: [Link](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html)

For example: Ctrl + x

```
type('x', KeyModifier.CTRL)
```

Arrow up:

```
App.focus("Notepad")
type(Key.UP)
```

I did use App.focus() in my example to make sure Sikuli is focusing on Notepad before clicking anything.

Comment: Enter is working just fine, but VK_UP(arrow up) does nothing. Works fine in notepad but not at all in game, just enter.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for: keyUp(), or type(Key.UP)

Comment: I'm using the Java sikuli library, not sikuli script. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. Can't get it to work with the link you sent me in Java. I tried kb.keyDown(Key.UP); to no avail. Where kb = new desktopkeyboard();